# Var key = Floor(map(...)); in p5.js "song" example project

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In the p5.js example project "song", there is a line of code that says

```
function mousePressed(){
    var key = floor(map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, notes.length));
    playNote(notes[key]);
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how exactly this works. I know that floor just rounds down to the nearest int. Map, though, I thought that was for translating an array into another array with some changes along the way.

Currently the notes play based on the x position of the mouse when pressed, but not the y position, so that's what I'm trying to make it do. Could anyone help me understand what this is doing, how it works, and how I could change it?

Comment: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try splitting it up into multiple steps and examining what's happening at each step?

```
function mousePressed(){
    var mappedValue = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, notes.length);
    console.log("mappedValue: " + mappedValue);
    var key = floor(mappedValue);
    console.log("key: " + key);
    playNote(notes[key]);
}
```

You might also try looking for the `map()` function in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map).